# How to replace a text plus brackets

Tags: javascript

Hi there how can   I replace  from this to this

```js
var str = document.getElementById('bos').innerHTML.replace('col_nr', "");
document.getElementById('bos').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="bos">
col_nr[504]
</div>
```

I want to be able to take only the number without brackets

Comment: do you have only a number, then you could replace all not number characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform more `replace()` to achieve your goal, demonstrated as below. Alternatively, you can use regular expression to perform your task as well.

```js
var str = document.getElementById('bos').innerHTML.replace('col_nr[', '').replace(']', '');
document.getElementById('bos').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="bos">
col_nr[504]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all not number characters.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('bos');

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, "");
```

```html
<div id="bos">
col_nr[504]
</div>
```